# section headers for only some sections in grouped uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I changed my `UITableView` to grouped (so the sections will scroll with the content).

The thing is - that some of the sections have no header (nil view, 0.01 height - as I read I should do)

There is still a gap between the sections.

How can I avoid it and still keep the behaviour of the section header not sticking around?

**Edit:**

The code I'm using (to be clear what is happening here)

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == contribsSectionNum)
    {
        return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContribDisplayHeader" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == contribsSectionNum)
    {
        return 43;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use a height of  0.0 instead of 0.01, that should do the trick!

Comment: tried it originally - the gaps are even bigger :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing heightForHeaderview delegate method of UITableview ?